# Cannot show and hide button in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this `isData` variable declared in my ts file

```
isData:boolean=false;
```

i have this button on my component

```
<button
        class="btn btn-primary"
        type="button"
        (click)="save()"
        *ngIf="isData===false"
      >
        Save
    </button>
```

`isData` is false but button is not shown i have tried with `isData=='false'` this also same issue.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: check console is there any error in console ?

Comment: You sure you imported `CommonModule` to whatever module provides this component?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
*ngIf="!isData"
```

Comment: Thanks tried but same issue

Comment: Have you imported `CommonModule` into your component? If not, `*ngIf` will not work

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you wish to enable the button when there `isData` is `false`.

However, `ngIf` needs to be `true` for it to enable the button.

@nate-kumar's answer should work assuming isData is false..

Answer (score 0):

If somehow ngIf is not working in angular, you may try hidden property with the inverse condition

```
<button
    class="btn btn-primary"
    type="button"
    (click)="save()"
    [hidden]="!isData"
  >
    Save
</button>
```

I hope this will help you for the problem.